# On the adiabatic theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, probability, density, adiabatic

In the [Adiabatic theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem) explanation on Wikipedia it says:

> Diabatic process: Rapidly changing conditions prevent the system from adapting its configuration during the process, hence the spatial probability density remains unchanged. Typically there is no eigenstate of the final Hamiltonian with the same functional form as the initial state. The system ends in a linear combination of states that sum to reproduce the initial probability density.
>
> Adiabatic process: Gradually changing conditions allow the system to adapt its configuration, hence the probability density is modified by the process. If the system starts in an eigenstate of the initial Hamiltonian, it will end in the corresponding eigenstate of the final Hamiltonian.

What does this refer to about the "probability density"?

Comment: Are you asking what is a "probability density"? This doesn't have much to do with the adiabatic theorem per se. By the way the definition of diabatic process is quite sloppy.

Comment: More what does in the context of adiabatic theorem